# When does Rails compile application.css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app where I replaced a `xxx.cs.scss` file in `assets/stylesheets/`.

I restart Rails on my Mac using `$ rails s`.

And the old `xxx.cs.scss` is still in the `application.css` file according to my browser.

Why wouldn't the `application.css` file get re-compiled?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your browser could cache the old file. Check it in incognito tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the asset compilation options in your `environments/development.rb` file to see if compilation is turned off.

Also, if you previously pre-compiled your assets (via `rake assets:precompile`) the compiled assets will take precedence over the on-demand compiled assets in your development environment. You may want to do `rake assets:clean` to get rid of any pre-compiled assets, then restart your local Rails server, and try again.